# How to pass data to another part of my html page with php?

Tags: php, html

Hi my question is: How can I pass data from my array to another part of my html code which is not in same file.

I have file item.php and index.php In index I have array with objects. Now I have to include item.php as many times as count of item in array and every time send different data to item.

Index.php

```
<?php
require_once('Subject.php');

$sub1 = new Subject(
    'informačné technológie',
    'Absolvent študijného odboru inteligentné technológie je kvalifikovaný odborný pracovník, k
                   torý má vedomosti a zručnosti z oblasti informačných technológií, programovania, počítačových sietí,
                   smart technológií, internetu vecí, databázových systémov, základov kybernetickej bezpečnosti, 
                   robotiky, 3D technológií, serverových a cloudových technológií, grafiky, základov elektroniky, 
                   optimalizácie riadenia procesov a problematiky súvisiacej s digitálnou firmou. Je schopný využívať
                    mäkké zručnosti v prezentovaní a vystupovaní.',
    'slider1.png',
    'video1.mp4');
$sub2 = new Subject(
    'elektrotechnika',
    'Absolvent študijného odboru inteligentné technológie je kvalifikovaný odborný pracovník,
                            ktorý má vedomosti a zručnosti z oblasti informačných technológií, programovania,
                            počítačových sietí, smart technológií, internetu vecí, databázových systémov, základov
                            kybernetickej bezpečnosti, robotiky, 3D technológií, serverových a cloudových technológií,
                            grafiky, základov elektroniky, optimalizácie riadenia procesov a problematiky súvisiacej s
                            digitálnou firmou. Je schopný využívať mäkké zručnosti v prezentovaní a vystupovaní.',
    'slider2.png',
    'video2.mp4'
);
... and moore subjects can be here

$subjects = array($sub1, $sub2, $sub3, $sub4, $sub5, $sub6, $sub7);

?>

<!--Header -->
<?php include("./parts/main/header.php") ?>
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="black-overlay"></div>
        <div id="dod-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                // This I need generate for every subject
                <?php include("./parts/carousel-item.php") ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<!--Footer -->
<?php include("./parts/main/footer.php") ?>
```

Item.php

```
<div class="carousel-item active d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="carousel-bg" style="background-image:url('assets/images/slider-electro.jpg')">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-content w-100 flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="top w-100 flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column flex-xl-row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center p-5">
            <div class="left mr-xl-5 order-2 order-xl-1">
                <h2 class="slider-caption border-red text-xl-left text-center">Informačné technológie</h2>
                <div class="cst-line d-xl-none mx-auto line-orange"></div>
                <p class="slider-text text-center text-xl-left my-3">
                    HERE COMES TEXT OF SUBJECT OBJECT
                </p>
                <div class="text-center text-xl-left">
                    <a href="HERE COMES LINK OF SUBJECT" target="_blank"
                       class="btn btn-orange">
                        <i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i>
                        Pustiť video
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right order-1 order-xl-2 mb-3 mb-xl-0">
                <div class="video-container position-relative">
                    <i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-4x position-absolute"></i>
                    <video>
                        <source src=" HERE COMES LINK OF SUBJECT" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <?php include("navigation.php") ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What array are you talking about?

Comment: oh I deleted it.. .my fault  -> edited

Comment: Under sub1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable in one file and then include another file from that first file, that same variable will also be available if that other file.

So in your example, if you have something like

```php
// index.php
<?php

$subjects = [
    new Subject('First Title'),
    new Subject('Another Title'),
];

foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    include('item.php');
}
```

Then whithin your `item.php` you can simply access the `$subject` variable (exactly as it would be available within that foreach loop):

```php
// item.php
<div class="carousel-content"> 
    <div class="text-center">
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $subject->getTitle() ) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, above is a more simplified version of your example, but it will work the same with your more detailed version.